# Compass SCSS lower case of color code

Tags: css, ruby, sass, compass-sass

In my team we have the same version of Compass (it`s Compass 0.12.2 Alnilam). When Compass compiles my SCSS the color code is changed from uppercase (#A0CAE3) to lowercase (#a0cae3) in the SCSS. Only I have this problem, other developers have the uppercase color code. Why?

Comment: What's the problem? It's the same color technically!

Comment: ather developers in my team write color code in upper case, and their compass compil it in upper case, we have the same config, the same version of compass and compil the same file. Every time, when i commit my changes, i overwrite their file and them overwrite mine, but file technically did`t change

Comment: This might not be related to Compass. Do you have any other linters or code formatters enabled? Basically - when you save the SCSS code, are the color values changed to lowercase in your SCSS file? Ah, this question is 4 years old, probably not still interested in responding....

Comment: @BrettDeWoody no the values in the SCSS file stay the exact same. The coworker told me he uses koala. I use command line compass calls (automatically called by my ide)

Comment: You must have a linter with an auto-fix option enabled.

Comment: So your coworkers are using Koala, and you're using Compass?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I thought koala uses compass under the hood

Answer (score 5):

Is should check version of "sass".

```
sass -v
```

Sass version 3.1.15 works fine in my case. Uninstall all installed "sass" versions with

```
gem uninstall sass
```

and install 3.1.15 version

```
gem install sass -v 3.1.15
```