# compass compile scss/sass options, arguments and directives

Tags: css, compass-sass, compass

When I run `compass compile` on some code I've checked out from a repository, I can see that my local install does generate a different output of the `.css` files than it did some previous compile on a different computer by some other developer at a different point in time but with the same `.scss` files.

Example changes (as diff):

```
   margin: 0;
-  background-color: #1D1D1D;
-  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
+  background-color: #1d1d1d;
   -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
+  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
+  -ms-border-radius: 5px;
+  -o-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px;
-  color: #fff;
+  color: white;
   display: inline-block;
```

This diff shows certain fields of change:

1. Expansion of prefixes: Next to `-moz-border-radius` the according prefix directives for `-ms-` and `-o-` were added
2. Change of hex-color-alpha-case: Recently uppercase (`#1D1D1D`) now lowercase (`#1d1d1d`)
3. Change of hex-colors into named colors: Recently short and sound (`#fff`) now named (`white`)

For each of these three points I'd like to learn where the behavior is controlled in ***compass***, from the directives and comments given in `config.rb` it's not visible to me what is controlled by what.

Additionally I don't know where the compass website/binary lists all available configuration directives.

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "/"
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"


# You can select your preferred output style here (can be overridden via the command line):
# output_style = :expanded or :nested or :compact or :compressed

# To enable relative paths to assets via compass helper functions. Uncomment:
relative_assets = true

# To disable debugging comments that display the original location of your selectors. Uncomment:
# line_comments = false


# If you prefer the indented syntax, you might want to regenerate this
# project again passing --syntax sass, or you can uncomment this:
# preferred_syntax = :sass
# and then run:
# sass-convert -R --from scss --to sass sass scss && rm -rf sass && mv scss sass
preferred_syntax = :sass
```

Comment: I think it's safe to say you don't need to [prefix border radius](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius)

Comment: X-Ref: [Compas scss lower case of colorcode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15517843/367456) - gives no answer. [Can I turn off SASS RGB -> Color Name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9611571/367456) is about SASS, gives no Compass directive and I checked the .scss code and it's not the case there [does not apply])  My compass version command is broken, same as here: [Compass only running in parts](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22035432/367456) (Kubuntu 14.04)

Comment: @jbutler483: Yes right. How can I control *Compass* to not insert those? What is the `config.rb` directive to control such behavior?

Comment: @To me it sounds like you're using a really old version or something. I don't use SASS tbh (prefer pure css), but I can tell you that since it *is* adding these, you can (probably) say that this 'older' technology. As for your numbered points, i'd wager this is to do with your PC configs and not the sass (since the 'changes' are mediocre, and make little-no impact on the end result.)

Comment: I see, yes I'm looking for Compass / SASS configuration and usage instructions. I mainly look for configuration directives here because I'd like to keep source changes limited (we commit the created .css files).